# Get "Missing client_id parameter" error on Facebook login using node.js /express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, express

I'm a front end developer trying to do backend stuff using express js, so this might be an easy one.
This is my problem:

I want a user to login using Facebook Social Login.

I have manage to set up the front end part so I have a:
* access_token
* app_id
* app_secret

Now I want to get a refresh-token on my backend, it looks like this:

```
var app_id = '122345abcd';
var app_secret = '111xxxx';
var accessToken = req.body.accessToken;
var baseURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com';

var url = baseURL + '/oauth/access_token?' +
    'grant_type=fb_exchange_token&amp;' +
    'client_id=' + app_id + '&amp;' +
    'client_secret=' + app_secret + '&amp;' +
    'fb_exchange_token=' + accessToken;


request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body.error.message);
});
```

This generates a very nice URL that looks right. It can look like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&amp;
client_id=122345abcd&amp;
client_secret=111xxxx&amp;
fb_exchange_token=EAACjzsDAL4oBALxjCRB5cTYTIdyTVYyg6z6do4IoN8R9b65dtGR7DCMvLNr4cRjeTxZBH7SGH0PNqLL5wfxf73lGORjkD0ZCP5c6WTkdTnCfvAPUZCTouRtTYY89UAgZAxO8GgGpjzZCSwB7W95YCVHKDKpNrcTH5R93bInV0UQZDZD
```

But what I get back is this.

```
"Missing client_id parameter."
```

What have I missed? 
There's clearly and client_id in the url, even though it's the app_id. But that seems to be right.

I have followed this guide:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

UPDATE: The guide above say you shall use &amp; in the URL. That is what breaks things. Use & instead.

```
var url = baseURL + '/oauth/access_token?' +
'grant_type=fb_exchange_token&' +
'client_id=' + app_id + '&' +
'client_secret=' + app_secret + '&' +
'fb_exchange_token=' + accessToken;
```

Comment: Can you show your created `URL` with  some invalid details?

Comment: This isn’t an HTML context, so `&amp;` have no place being in there. Replace them with simple `&`.

Comment: Yes, it should be `&`